# combinig regex partly using | not working c++

Tags: c++, regex

so this is going to be a regex for email address.
username: capital and small letters, digits, and underscore and dot

```
^[A-Za-z0-9._]+
```

then there's @ and domain: capital and small letters and digits

```
@[A-Za-z0-9]+
```

then there's dot and tld: at least 2 characters (letters and digits) and can have maximum one dot.
I used | to have both at least 2 characters and maximum one dot:

```
([A-Za-z0-9]{2,}|[.]{0,1})
```

so the complete regex is this:

```
regex reg ("^[A-Za-z0-9._]+@[A-Za-z0-9]+\\.([A-Za-z0-9]{2,}|[.]{0,1})$");
```

but the maximum one dot rule isn't working. when I input zohal@gmail.df.g (not real of course) it gives false. it does work in other cases like zohal@gmail.com though.

Comment: Try `regex reg(R"(^[A-Za-z0-9._]+@(?=(?:[^A-Za-z0-9]*[A-Za-z0-9]){2})[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$)")`, see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/033NpV/1).

Comment: @WikitorStribizew That gives true even for `zohal@gmail` which is not desirable. So it should be: `R"(^[A-Za-z0-9._]+@(?=(?:[^A-Za-z0-9]*[A-Za-z0-9]){2})[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)+$)"`

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
regex reg(R"(^[A-Za-z0-9._]+@[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)+$)")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/033NpV/2)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[A-Za-z0-9._]+` - 1 or more letters, digits, `.` or `_`
- `@` - a `@` char
- `[A-Za-z0-9]+` - 1 or more letters or digits
- `(?:\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)+` - 1 or more occurrences of a dot and then 1 or more letters or digits
- `$` - an end of string position.

Since there are two `+` quantified patterns after `@`, you do not need an explicit `(?=(?:[^A-Za-z0-9]*[A-Za-z0-9]){2})` lookahead to require at least two letters or digits.